# Two application using  SQL Server Compact edition at the same time

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-ce

Is it possible to have two independent programs using the same SQL Server Compact 4.0 database at the same time?

Comment: whether it is a lightweight database that is able to do?

Comment: @marc_s this was true for the 3.5 version of SQL CE, 4.0 however is capable of multiple access environments (such as ASP.NET)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, of course, if both programs run on the same computer and the database file resides on a local drive. SQL Server Compact supports up to 256 connections. Make sure to use the exact same connection string from both processes.

Comment: How do you mean - exact same connection string from both processes?

two diferent programms with ado.net entity framework using one .sdf?

Comment: Yes, the same EF connection string contents from both apps.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171750.aspx) it says so you can do it

> Multiple applications—multiple applications on a device can access a single database at the same time. The developer is not required to manage exclusive connections. Users can use database tools, such as SQL Server Compact 3.5 Query Analyzer, while another application is connected to the database.